# How to configure kernel page table isolation feature off in linux kernel source code?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel

Which option should I choose to disable kpti when executing the `make menuconfig` step to avoid the performance degrade of meltdown bug fix?

Answer (score 0):

First `Security options`, then `Remove the kernel mapping in user mode`.